# Undestand the Start_date of a dag

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-webserver

Here's my code for a simple airflow dag.

[image]

Today is 2022-07-15. I run the simple_dag. The dates that start by July 12, 20:00 and so on, on top of some dagrun means what ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is relate to your start_date that is from 13 July with difference of 4 hours from UTC.

Airflow his running the dag every 10 min from your start_date.

for more info : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date